# singledispatchmethod and class method decorators in python 3.8

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-decorators

I am trying to use one of the new capabilities of python 3.8 (currently using 3.8.3). Following [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.singledispatchmethod) I tried the example provided in the docs:

```py
from functools import singledispatchmethod
class Negator:
    @singledispatchmethod
    @classmethod
    def neg(cls, arg):
        raise NotImplementedError("Cannot negate a")

    @neg.register
    @classmethod
    def _(cls, arg: int):
        return -arg

    @neg.register
    @classmethod
    def _(cls, arg: bool):
        return not arg

Negator.neg(1)
```

This, however, yields the following error:

```
...
TypeError: Invalid first argument to `register()`: <classmethod object at 0x7fb9d31b2460>. Use either `@register(some_class)` or plain `@register` on an annotated function.
```

How can I create a generic class method? Is there something I am missing in my example?

**Update:**

I have read Aashish A's answer and it seems lik an on-going issue. I have managed to solve my problem the following way.

```py
from functools import singledispatchmethod
class Negator:
    @singledispatchmethod
    @staticmethod
    def neg(arg):
        raise NotImplementedError("Cannot negate a")

    @neg.register
    def _(arg: int):
        return -arg

    @neg.register
    def _(arg: bool):
        return not arg

print(Negator.neg(False))
print(Negator.neg(-1))
```

This seems to work in version 3.8.1 and 3.8.3, however it seems it shouldn't as I am not using the staticmethod decorator on neither the undescore functions. This DOES work with classmethods, even tho the issue seems to indicate the opposite.

Keep in mind if you are using an IDE that the linter won't be happy with this approach, throwing a lot of errors.

Comment: Terminology note: you are defining class methods, not static methods. Python distinguishes between the two, as a class method receives a class as an implicit argument, while a static method receives no implicit argument (and for both types of methods, the behavior is the same whether invoked from a class or an instance of the class).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I was wrong, probably because I was testing also with the staticmethod decorator, which doesn't work as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in the functools library documented in [this issue](https://bugs.python.org/issue39679).

Answer (score 5):

This bug is no longer present in Python >= 3.9.8. In Python 3.9.8, the code for `singledispatchmethod` [has been tweaked](https://docs.python.org/release/3.9.8/whatsnew/changelog.html) to ensure it works with type annotations and `classmethod`s/`staticmethod`s. In Python 3.10+, however, the bug was solved as a byproduct of changing the way `classmethod`s and `staticmethod`s behave with respect to the `__annotations__` attribute of the function they're wrapping.

In Python 3.9:

```
>>> x = lambda y: y
>>> x.__annotations__ = {'y': int}
>>> c = classmethod(x)
>>> c.__annotations__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#37>", line 1, in <module>
    c.__annotations__
AttributeError: 'classmethod' object has no attribute '__annotations__'
```

In Python 3.10+:

```
>>> x = lambda y: y
>>> x.__annotations__ = {'y': int}
>>> c = classmethod(x)
>>> c.__annotations__
{'y': <class 'int'>}
```

This change appears to have solved the issue with `singledispatchmethod`, meaning that in Python 3.9.8 and Python 3.10+, the following code works fine:

```
from functools import singledispatchmethod

class Negator:
    @singledispatchmethod
    @classmethod
    def neg(cls, arg):
        raise NotImplementedError(f"Cannot negate object of type '{type(arg).__name__}'")

    @neg.register
    @classmethod
    def _(cls, arg: int) -> int:
        return -arg

    @neg.register
    @classmethod
    def _(cls, arg: bool) -> bool:
        return not arg

print(Negator.neg(1))
print(Negator.neg(False))
```

Answer (score 2):

A workaround, while the bugfix is not merged, is to patch [`singledispatchmethod.register()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.singledispatchmethod):

```py
from functools import singledispatchmethod

def _register(self, cls, method=None):
    if hasattr(cls, '__func__'):
        setattr(cls, '__annotations__', cls.__func__.__annotations__)
    return self.dispatcher.register(cls, func=method)

singledispatchmethod.register = _register
```